# Get data from a recurrent day of the week from a Mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a Mysql table that contains data for every day, let's assume it's a log table. Every row has an information, a number, with date and hour (with minutes and seconds). Example:

```
|daydate             |data_as_number|
|2020-03-01 14:38:24 |            12|
|2020-03-01 14:41:24 |            13|
|2020-03-02 11:28:31 |             6|
|...                 |            ..|
```

I'm not that good at SQL queries, so is there a way to extract data from that table, with a single query, that can answer to this need:

```
Get all the rows  of every Wednesday from 16:00 to 18:00, starting from the 1st of March to 31 of May?
```

My first solution is to use X queries, every single query contains the date and hour as WHERE condition, then I can merge the results, somthing similar to this:

```
SELECT data_as_number FROM table WHERE daydate> 2020-03-01 16:00:00 AND daydate < 2020-03-01 18:00:00
```

then add 7 to the date

```
SELECT data_as_number FROM table WHERE daydate> 2020-03-08 16:00:00 AND daydate < 2020-03-08 18:00:00
```

and so on... Is this a good solution? Or does it exists something better in SQL ?

Answer (score 3):

> Get all the rows  of every Wednesday from 16:00 to 18:00, starting from the 1st of March to 31 of May?

This is a combination of conditions in a `where` clause:

```
where weekday(daydate) = 2 and         -- Wednesday
      time(daydate) >= '16:00:00' and  -- time condition
      time(daydate) < '18:00:00 and    -- time condition
      daydate >= '2020-03-01' and      -- date condition
      daydate < '2020-06-01'
```

Actually, the year isn't specified for the date condition.  If that is independent of year, then you can use the `month()` function:

```
where weekday(daydate) = 2 and         -- Wednesday
      time(daydate) >= '16:00:00' and  -- time condition
      time(daydate) < '18:00:00 and    -- time condition
      month(daydate) in (3, 4, 5)
```